# Router doesn't give IP address to connected devices

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, 3g

I have a mikrotik router that i configure with Openwrt Luci. I created a 3g interface which is working because i see data on the Rx and Tx. Then I created a WiFi connection linked to my 3G interface.

The problem is when I try to connect to the router with a device (pc, phone), it doesn't connect. I think it doesn't give it an IP address.

Comment: It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Did you turn on DHCP? Sometimes alternative firmware doesn't turn it on by default. If there's a GUI interface, then there should be a DHCP setting in there somewhere, I'm unfamiliar with the Luci version, but most have a generally similar layout, in Tomato & some other DD-WRT's it's under Basic Network settings.

Or, here's the help page for [OpenWRT's DNS and DHCP configuration](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci/dhcp), it's got many many settings & involve editing settings files